# Multiplying matrices in Eigen c++ gives wrong dimensions

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication, eigen

I'm having trouble understanding why I am getting a 10x10 matrix as a result from multiplying a 10x3 matrix with a 3x10 matrix using the Eigen library in c++.

By following the documentation at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html I came up with

```
const int NUM_OBSERVATIONS = 10;
const int NUM_DIMENSIONS = 3;

MatrixXf localspace(NUM_DIMENSIONS, NUM_OBSERVATIONS);
MatrixXf rotatedlocalspace(NUM_OBSERVATIONS, NUM_DIMENSIONS);
MatrixXf covariance(NUM_DIMENSIONS, NUM_DIMENSIONS);

covariance = (rotatedlocalspace * localspace) / (NUM_OBSERVATIONS - 1);

cout << covariance << endl;
```

Output gives a 10x10 matrix, when I am trying to obtain a 3x3 covariance matrix for each dimension (These are mean centered XYZ points). "localspace" and "rotatedlocalspace" are both filled with float values when covariance is calculated.

How do I get the correct covariance matrix?

Comment: Because multiplying an [MxK] matrix by a [KxN] matrix gives you a [MxN] matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eigen is correct, as it reproduces basic math: if `A` is a matrix of dimension `n x m` and `B` has dimension `m x k`, then `A*B` has the dimension `n x k`.

Applied to your problem, if your matrix `rotatedlocalspace` is of dimension `10 x 3` and `localspace` has dimension `3 x 10`, then `rotatedlocalspace*localspace` has dimension

```
(10 x 3) * (3 x 10) ->  10 x 10.
```

The scalar division you apply further doesn't change the dimension.

If you expect a different dimension, then try to commute the factors in the matrix product. This you will obtain a `3x3` matrix.